# Using Swift's Location BLE GPS To Decode location_and_speed

Tags: ios, swift, gps, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral

My application currently works as I am able to retrieve the values from the decoding **location_and_speed** characteristic. However, I am having difficulties reading the documentation from Bluetooth to decode/extract the values from the device.

Below is my code:

```
 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor 

    characteristic: CBCharacteristic,  error: Error?) {           
            print(#function)
            print(characteristic.value?.count ?? 0)
            guard let data = characteristic.value else {return}

            let byteArray = [UInt8](data)

            // TODO: decode the value to available gps data???
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thank You!

Comment: Which Bluetooth characteristic are you trying to decode?  Can you link to the documentation on the Bluetooth site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a BLE Peripheral Characteristic and checking its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894363/reading-a-ble-peripheral-characteristic-and-checking-its-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging around and with thanks to xdappcactory.com
I found the solution. this is the struct that I came up with, only decoding speed and location, but still usable

```
// MARK: - decode helpers
struct LocationAndSpeed {
    enum PositionStatus : Int {
        case none
        case ok
        case estimated
        case lastKnown
    }

    enum SpeedAndDistanceFormat : Int {
        case _2D
        case _3D
    }

    enum ElevationSource : Int  {
        case position
        case barometricAirPressure
        case databaseService
        case other
    }

    enum HeadingSource : Int {
        case movementBased
        case magneticCompass
    }

    let instantaneousSpeedPresent: Bool
    let totalDistancePresent : Bool
    let locationPressent : Bool
    let elevationPressent : Bool
    let headingPressent : Bool
    let rollingTimePressent : Bool
    let utcTimePressent : Bool
    let positionStatus : PositionStatus
    let speedAndDistanceFormat : SpeedAndDistanceFormat
    let elevationSource : ElevationSource
    let headingSource : HeadingSource

    let speed : CLLocationSpeed?
    let distance : CLLocationDistance?
    let latitude : CLLocationDegrees
    let longitude : CLLocationDegrees
    let elevation : CLLocationDistance?
    let heading : CLLocationDirection?
    let rollingTime : TimeInterval?
    let utcTime : Date?

    enum LocationAndSpeedError : Error {
        case invalidSize
    }

    init(data: Data) throws {
        guard data.count >= 10 else {throw LocationAndSpeedError.invalidSize}
      //  let byteArray = [UInt8](data)

        // handle the flags
        let flagsData = data.subdata(in: 0..<2)
        let flags = flagsData.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) -> UInt16 in return pointer.pointee }
        instantaneousSpeedPresent = (flags & .speed) != 0
        totalDistancePresent = (flags & .distance) != 0
        locationPressent = (flags & .location) != 0
        elevationPressent = (flags & .elevation) != 0
        headingPressent = (flags & .heading) != 0
        rollingTimePressent = (flags & .rollingTime) != 0
        utcTimePressent = (flags & .utcTime) != 0

        positionStatus = PositionStatus(rawValue: Int((flags & .position) >> 7)) ?? .none
        speedAndDistanceFormat = SpeedAndDistanceFormat(rawValue: Int((flags & .format) >> 9)) ?? ._2D
        elevationSource = ElevationSource(rawValue: Int((flags & .elevationSource) >> 10)) ?? .other
        headingSource = HeadingSource(rawValue: Int((flags & .headinSource) >> 12)) ?? .movementBased

        var index = 2
        if (instantaneousSpeedPresent){
            let speedData = data.subdata(in: index ..< index + 2)
            speed = Double(speedData.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) -> UInt16 in return pointer.pointee }) / 100
            index += 2
        } else {
            speed = -1
        }

       if (totalDistancePresent) {
            distance = 0//Double((UInt32(byteArray[index]) << 16) + (UInt32(byteArray[index + 1]) << 8) + UInt32(byteArray[index + 2])) / 10
            index += 3
        } else {
            distance = -1
        }

        // I don't know if this is the right data....



        let latData = data.subdata(in: index..<index+4)
        let lat = latData.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<Int32>) -> Int32 in return pointer.pointee }
        latitude = Double(lat) / 10000000.0

        index += 4

        let lonData = data.subdata(in: index..<index+4)
        let lon = lonData.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<Int32>) -> Int32 in return pointer.pointee }


        longitude = Double(lon) / 10000000.0

        index += 4

        elevation = nil
        heading = nil
        rollingTime = nil
        utcTime = nil
    }

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}
```